# Android:How to avoid XML verification failed error and Upgrading to 2.x SDK successfully?

Tags: android

I have setup for Android development with 1.5 SDK on Mac O.S X - Eclipse 3.5. I want to upgrade the SDK, so as i followed to choose Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager from Eclipse. But it throws error as follows:

> XML verification failed for
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
>   Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk- repository'. Failed to fetch URL

I tried "http" instead of https, but still getting the same error. I don't know why such crap error comes. If i see Android website,
https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
its confusing.

Could someone guide me easily to update Android SDK to 2.x or later without uninstalling my current setup environment.

Comment: At first check the system language in ControlPanel>>Region(/Language in windows 7) and if your regional language is opted there, change it to English US/Uk and run SDK now. If it still doesn't work go to this [YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6SlQBZiP91s) and follow steps.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a very old version of the tools, you will need to download a newer starter package from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

The reason is that the schema of the repository XML file changed when we released rev 5, but only tools in revision 4 or higher can adapt to schema changes.

By the way once you download the new starter package you can replace the tools folder from your previous installation with the new one. That way you don't have to change PATH env var or any other setup you have.

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I need to download the zip file which shows as "Mac OS X (intel)-android-sdk_r05-mac_86.zip 19871714 bytes-6fcfeed0e1c36624c926551637eb3308" available in your link provided and replace only "Tools" folder from this one to existing working copy of "~\Library\android-sdk-mac_x86-1.5_r3\Tools" folder. And then again do i need to try "Window->Android SDK and AVD Manager" to upgrade to new SDK?

Comment: And one more question, you were talking about old version of tools, where can i find what version of tools currently i have? I know there is a Tools folder in this path "~\Library\android-sdk-mac_x86-1.5_r3\Tools", but how do i know what version of tool is this?
Could you please answer for me asap for my above query and this query?

Comment: As you said i downloaded "android-sdk-mac_86" zip file. Replaced only "Tools" folder from the new one to existing working folder. When i launch Eclipse now, it shows 'The Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 0.9.6 or above. Current version if 0.9.3.v200090 . Please update to latest version of ADT. What should i do now? Am i doing correct or wrong?

Comment: I resolved all the problems, now i'm able to download latest SDK's thru Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Comment: The version of the tools is now displayed in the "about" panel in the SDK/AVD Manager but I don't think it was in the first that shipped wit h the 1.5_r3 but it was probably version 1 or 2.

Comment: Hello, thank you. After did upgradation upto 2.1 SDK version, restarted my Macbook. I launch Eclipse - WIndows->Android SDK and AVD Manager, but it doesn't launch at all. Is it known issue? Why does clicking on Android SDK and AVD Manager, not launching after did upgrade?

Comment: I did launch Eclipse -clean terminal option (./eclipse -clean -vmargs -XstartOnFirstThread) but still "Android SDK and AVD Manager" doesn't launch.

Answer (score 1):

Error:

XML verification failed for https://dlssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml.
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Solution:

This error occurs on Mac because, Java 6 is not installed by default on osX 10.5.6 or before and you need Java 6 to run Android AVD and SDK Manager.

The easiest way to overcome this error is by installing the latest version of Java.

You can find [this blog](http://luckyviplav.wordpress.com/2011/03/23/handling-xml-verification-failed-error-on-mac-while-installing-packages-in-android-sdk-and-avd-manager/) useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the error **XML verification failed for https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml. Error: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'sdk:sdk- repository'. Failed to fetch URL**

in mac os, then download android sdk (Mac OS X (intel) android-sdk_r15-macosx.zip) from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. Unzip this package and copy this unzip package on your mac root directory (Macintosh HD) and rename this unzip package as android-sdk. Now open android-sdk->tools->android. The sdk update will start automatically. You dont need to install java 6. It is automatically installed in your mac os.